# Referencing a form name in a recordset update

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I have an Audit function that appends a record to an Audit table each time an Add, Edit or Delete occurs. Part of the information it appends come from controls within the subform.

This causes problems because one subform may have several parent forms. For this reason I need to identify the parent form name, as it will change the names of several controls.

```
varParent = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
Select Case UserAction
    Case "EDIT"
        For Each ctl In Screen.ActiveForm.Controls
            If ctl.Tag = "Audit" Then
                If Nz(ctl.Value) <> Nz(ctl.OldValue) Then
                    With rst
                        .AddNew
                        ![Record_ID] = Forms! & varParent & .SubFormName.Record_ID.Value
.........
```

I know that last line is absolutely not correct, but I'm not even sure where to start. Maybe it would be easier to just do a few if-then cases and say where varParent = X Then set that value specifically.

My only concern with that solution is that it'll take far more time. Help?

Comment: For this, accessing the form by name, you'd need something to access that collection via a string.  By default, VB creates a controls collection containing these references. 
 You'd need something along the lines of

`Screen.ActiveForm.Controls("SubFormName").Record_ID.Value`

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, but does `Forms(varParent)` help at all?